# A word for being willing to accept the decisions and/or actions of machines

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary, compounds, compound-words, being

Is there a word that describes the attitude of a human willingly accepting the decisions and/or actions of machines (automation, robots, control systems, etc).
e.g. I have just bought a new car with autonomous braking which initially I did not trust and tended to turn off. Some models of human/machine interaction are based on trust building as the person’s knowledge of the purpose of a machine, how it functions and what is its actual performance becomes clear and understood. I distrust the autonomous braking on my car even though I have some idea of its purpose and how it functions. I cannot however verify its performance because I cannot test it without potentially wrecking my new car (simulate a frontal collision). The essential characteristics of the relationship between human and machine seems to be that the machine extends human capability and can do things (in the case of autonomous braking) beyond our cognitive ability and speed of response. Also the human's life or safety depends on it and there is no alternative or escape because the actions needed when the machine detects danger and intervenes happens independently of our own ability to act.
I welcome any suggestions for a term that describes our attitude towards "submission to  machines" in this particular context that involves our personal safety.

Comment: Welcome to English.Stackexchange! Your post is relevant. I would say you have written piece describing, "submission by default"...

Comment: Your own term *trust* seems like it would work here.

Comment: You might want to break  up that paragraph into two or three paragraphs. It makes my eyes glaze over.

Comment: It wasn't all that long ago when mankind had to puzzle out what to do about manmade objects that were durable, valuable, and within reach of the population as a whole. We invented systems of ownership and inheritance; and we established cultural conventions on how the natural world and the manmade world were related. These were fiddled with over the last few centuries as manmade objects played an ever greater role in human affairs. But we are past that now, fiddling with the old scheme isn't going to work anymore.

Comment: This is an interesting question, well put.  Part of an answer is that the answer will depend on the stage we have reached.  So, at some time in the future the technology may have proved itself, with the glitches removed and fewer accidents/injuries/death than before.  Then we shall probably call people still declining to use fully automated vehicles 'technophobes'.  Right now, when caution is probably the norm, we probably wont use a special term.  If you have to (for spreadsheets/statistics) 'joiners'/'decliners' would be suitably neutral and short.

Answer (score 2):

The OP's mention of *willingly accept, distrust, no alternative or escape,* and *submission to machines* leads me to:

**acquiesce**

> To accept, comply, or submit tacitly or passively -- often used with
> *in* or *to* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiesce)

> Accept something reluctantly but without protest. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/acquiesce)

> Turning to the only device left to my control...ironically, the Mouse,
> I reluctantly **acquiesce** to the computer's logic and request,
> terminating the session. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dogged_and_Determined/_2_4KLuD37MC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=acquiesce%20to%20computer%20control&pg=PA145&printsec=frontcover).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an 'automatic decision'. But this does not describes "willingly accepting" or even just "acceptance" whether "willing" or not; and nor is an 'automatic decision' made neccessarily by machines or algorithms. You can say 'he decided automatically' in the sense the decision was already a foregone conclusion.

I don't think there is such a word which is specifically orientated to machines, automation, robots or algorithms and which probably reveals a great deal about the psychology, politics and ethics of how humans view automata, specifically that machines and algorithms are designed by humans and so the ultimate decision and responsibility is by humans. It obviously has a legal dimension too.

In a sense, that there is no popular term for such a notion reveals an ethical, political and legal recognition that such 'automatic' decision-making ultimately remains in the hands of humans and it's there that the real responsility lies. Colloquially, it's where the buck stops.